# Setting display scaling and resolution with xrandr

Tags: x11, xrandr

I just completed a fresh install of arch and I'm configuring the i3-gaps window manager.

Using a 2560x1440 monitor, all the graphics (text, symbols, etc..) are really small and I'd like to adjust that.

If I simply change the scaling with xrandr, to 0.8x0.8 with:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --scale 0.8x0.8
```

the graphics scale up a bit to reasonable dimensions, but my resolution goes down as a result. Calling

```
xdpyinfo | grep -B 2 resolution
```

before scaling returns:

```
screen #0:
  dimensions:    2560x1440 pixels (677x381 millimeters)
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

while after scaling I get:

```
screen #0:
  dimensions:    2048x1152 pixels (541x304 millimeters)
  resolution:    96x96 dots per inch
```

so the resolution goes down as a result of that. Also, everything looks a bit "washed out" and off when I scale up the graphics.

My question is: how can I scale up the graphics to what I would get using a 1920x1080 resolution, while still maintaining the 2560x1440 resolution and its crispness?